# Bind event to "remove" jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I got this function:

```
(function($) {
    var origAppend = $.fn.append;
    $.fn.append = function() {
        return origAppend.apply(this, arguments).trigger("append");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It binds a event to the jQuery's "append" function (I will mind the "appendTo" latter).

It works perfectly. I tried to change it to make it work with "remove" function as well:

```
(function($) {
    var origRemove = $.fn.remove;
    $.fn.remove = function() {
        return origRemove.apply(this, arguments).trigger("remove");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on “doesn’t work”? Do you get an error? Does it fail to remove the element? Does the event not fire?

Comment: No errors, the event simply doesn't fire.

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aFhn8/**, you're triggering an event on an element that no longer exists, as you've removed it.

Comment: Thank you adeno, it worked! Your comment should be posted as answer.

Comment: @PedroHenrique - Happy to help, added an answer !

Comment: @adeneo - it's not quite true that the DOM element no longer exists.  It still exists until there are no more references to it and it's garbage collected (which is not something that happens inside this method - it could happen later).  `.remove()` does get rid of jQuery event handlers though which is probably the main issue here since the event handlers for the "remove" event will be removed and thus not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're triggering the `remove` event after the original `remove()` method is called, at that time the element is removed, and all associated data and event handlers are removed with it.

You have to trigger the event before the element is removed

```
var origRemove = $.fn.remove;
$.fn.remove = function() {
    this.trigger("remove");
    return origRemove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aFhn8/1/)